# Regex to keep specific characters from string

Tags: regex

I need a regex command that can be used to only keep 0-9,a-z,A-Z, "-" and ":".

How can I do this?

(Also, I would like to know if there are any good Regex GUI editors)

Comment: What do you mean by `Regex GUI editors`? There are a number of regexp fiddle sites, where you can see the effects of your regexp on some text interactively.

Comment: I mean one that you can type in what you want and it output a regex command.

Comment: I don't think so. What language would you type in what you want?

Comment: Example:

Input: "a-z,A-Z,0-9,-,:"
Output: [0-9a-zA-Z\-:]

Comment: That's a trivial case, most regular expressions are more complex, with repetitions, optional and alternative elements, capturing and non-capturing groups, wildcards, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a character class, the following will match any one of the characters you listed:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z\-:]
```

And here is a regex that will match strings that contain only those characters:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z\-:]*$
```

If you don't want to allow empty strings, change the `*` to `+`.

It wasn't exactly clear if this is what you were trying to do, if you are actually trying to remove all other characters except the listed one, you can negate the character class by adding `^` to the beginning of it, like so:

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z\-:]
```

This will match all characters except the ones listed, so you should be able to replace matches of the above regex with an empty string to remove the unwanted characters.

Comment: One more question:

Is it possible to keep newline and carriage return characters also?

Comment: You should be able to add `\r` and `\n` to the character class.